# Python : create random float and insert automatically in database

Tags: python, random, insert, sqlalchemy

I've working on statistics related project and I need to create random float, and insert it into mysql database. 
I wonder when I try to create random floats, is there any way to set standard deviation or range of floats.
Also, I would like to know is it possible to insert those random floats using sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways of creating a random float, in you case since you want a range and a standard deviation most easy way would be:

```
from random import uniform
# Using Uniform:
# uniform(float1MIN,float2MAX)
randomFloat = uniform(1.0, 2.0)
print randomFloat
>> 1.4325772628557872
```

After this insert this as you would insert a regular variable.

About sqlalchemy, if you want more info about the basics you can read it in here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html

Side note: You can merge two ints and a dot into a float.

```
from random import randint
int1 = randint(1,10)
int2 = randint(321321,4902309)
futureFloat = str(int1) + '.' + str(int2)
myFloat = float(futureFloat)
```